# How to show/hide Input fields based on radiobutton/checkbox selection in sap ui5?

Tags: radio-button, sapui5, show-hide

so I am doing a form and I need to display, lets say both of the Inputs if a radiobutton is selected. If it's not selected, nothing should happen and the user won't see these Inputs. They should be hidden if the box is not selected.
In my view and controller I have so far the following:

```
<RadioButton id="ch1"  select="checkDone" text="Check" />
                                <FlexBox  class="sapUiSmallMarginEnd" id="f1">
                                    <Input value="ssss" />
                                </FlexBox>
                                <FlexBox direction="Column" id="f2">
                                    <Input value="dddd" />
                                </FlexBox>



checkDone: function (oEvent) {
            var checkV = this.byId("ch1").getSelected(); // not working         
            document.getElementById("f1").style.visibility = 'hidden'
```

Edit: I managed to make them appear using

```
this.getView().byId('f1').setVisible(true); 
this.getView().byId('f2').setVisible(true);
```

Now i want to make them disappear when checkbox is unchecked.

Answer (score 1):

It's better to use a JSON model for something like this. This has the advantage that if you want to display the input fields for any other reason, you only have to set the property to true at that point.

You can store all the properties you need to control the UI in this JSON model.

manifest:

```
"MyViewModel": {
    "type": "sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel"
 },
```

Controller (Set initial value)

```
  onInit: function(){
     var oMyMViewModel = this.getModel("MyViewModel");
     oMyViewModel.setProperty("/CheckboxSelected", false);
   }
```

View:

```
<CheckBox selected="{MyViewModel>/CheckboxSelected}" text="Check" />

<FlexBox  visible="{MyViewModel>/CheckboxSelected}" class="sapUiSmallMarginEnd">
    <Input value="ssss" />
</FlexBox>
<FlexBox visible="{MyViewModel>/CheckboxSelected}" direction="Column">
    <Input value="dddd" />
</FlexBox>
```

Comment: thanks for the reply but the page is now not loading. Is the controller function right? shouldnt be "new JSONModel" since i have not initiated it yet?

Comment: Your JSON Model is initiated in manifest.json. What's the error?